# emoji insert ?? in database utf8mb4_bin mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert

I'm having trouble inserting emoticons emoji in mySQL, it inserts "??" for each emoticon .. my table is already utf8mb4_bin as to how do I insert correctly? will be PHP?

I am using post method to insert into database